# Recursive function with unique name in php

Tags: php, wordpress, recursion

1) I am selecting a goat from dropdown list and having goat_id and its sire and dam both fields are stores parent goat_name.

2) I am try to call it recursively with goat_name, for each sire and dam both fields.

```
function generate_tree($goat_id) 
{
    global $wpdb;

    // get all records from database whose parent is $id
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM mm_goats WHERE id = %d", $goat_id);
    $row2 = $wpdb->get_row($sql, ARRAY_A);

    //check if there are any results

        if(!empty($row2))
        {
            echo "<ul>";
            if($row2['sire'] != "" || $row2['dam'] != "")
            {
                //print result and call function to check if it has children
                echo "<li>Sire: ".$row2['sire']."</li>";
                echo "<li>Dam: ".$row2['dam']."</li>";
                generate_tree($row2['id']);
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }
}
```

I used this function its goes to infinite loop with first selected sire and dam.

Follow this structure.
for ex:
[image]

Comment: you're passing in the ID of the current goat to your recursive function, not the IDs of the sire/dams, so you do `generate_tree(42);`, which then calls `generate_tree(42)`, which then calls etc....

Comment: How can one encounter an infinite loop with no loop?

Comment: Oh. I see it now.. I thought @MarcB Was talking gibberish.. I was wrong.. oops

Comment: can you have some example code then pls tell me.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM mm_goats WHERE id = %d", $goat_id);
                                                    ^^^^^^^
```

You fetch the indicated ID, which then is used in the recusrive call:

```
            generate_tree($row2['id']);
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So you just keep fetching information about the **SAME** goat on every recursive iteration. Goat #42 -> Goat #42 -> Goat #42 etc... until you hit the recursion/memory limit.

Your recursive call should be using the dam/sire IDs:

```
  generate_tree($row['id_of_dam']);
  generate_tree($row['id_of_sire']);
```

instead.

```
#42 -> #7,10 -> #1,2,3,4 etc...
```

Answer (score -1):

You should update your table structure to something like

```
mm_goats
   - id
   - sire_id
   - dam_id
   - name
```

you can then do an inner join to select them

```
SELECT `mm_goats`.`name`, `mm_goats`.`sire_id`, `mm_goats`.`dam_id`, `sire`.`name` AS `sire_name`, `dam`.`name` AS `dam_name`
    FROM `mm_goats`
        INNER JOIN `mm_goats` AS `sire` ON `mm_goats`.`sire_id` = `sire`.`id`
        INNER JOIN `mm_goats` AS `dam` ON `mm_goats`.`dam_id` = `dam`.`id`
    WHERE `mm_goats`.`id` = %d
```

after this you can then initiate your recursion

```
echo "<li>Sire: ".$row2['sire_name'];
generate_tree($row2['sire_id']);
echo "</li>";
echo "<li>Dam: ".$row2['dam_name'];
generate_tree($row2['dam_id']);
echo "</li>";
```